# Python - Threading - execute simultaneously

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object

I have this example code:

```
# some imports that I'm not including in the question

class daemon:
    def start(self):
        # do something, I'm not including what this script does to not write useless code to the question
        self.run()

    def run(self):
        """You should override this method when you subclass Daemon.

        It will be called after the process has been daemonized by 
        start() or restart().
        """

class MyDaemon(daemon):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    daemonz = MyDaemon('/tmp/daemon-example.pid')
    daemonz.start()

def firstfunction():
    # do something
    secondfunction()

def secondfunction():
    # do something
    thirdfunction()

def thirdfunction():
    # do something

# here are some variables set that I am not writing
firstfunction()
```

How can I exit from the run(self) function of class "daemon" and going on executing the firstfunction() like written in the last line? I'm a newbie with Python, and I'm trying to learn

**# EDIT**
I managed to implement the daemon class into the treading class. But I'm in the same situation of first, the script stays in daemon class and doesn't execute the other lines.

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def daemonize(self):
    # istructions to daemonize my script process

    def run(self):
        self.daemonize()


def my_function():
    print("MyFunction executed") # never executed

thread = MyThread()
thread.start()
my_function() # the process is successfully damonized but
              # this function is never executed
```

Comment: Your code will get stuck in the while loop in MyDaemon won't it? That's why your code is never reaching firstfunction().

Comment: The `while True` condition in the `run()` method will keep your program in the loop forever. Did you intend to have some other condition instead?

Comment: actually I have to write the next instructions in def run(self) of class "daemon", but at the moment I didn't write anything because I asked what I can do to pass to the other commands out of class, like in the last line "firstfunction()". How can I do?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you going to keep asking the same question (and deleting the previous) each day until someone writes your project for you or at least a course-level tutorial on threading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the `break`keyword to exit loops, and continue to the next line. `return` can be used to exit functions.

```
class daemon:
    def start(self):
        self.run()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            break
        return
        print()  # This never executes
```

If you want MyDaemon to run alongside the rest of your code, you have to make it a process or thread. Code then automatically continues to the next line, while the MyDaemon class (thread/process) runs.

```
import threading  


class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        print("Thread started")
        while True:
            pass


def my_function():
    print("MyFunction executed")

thread = MyThread()
thread.start()        # executes run(self)
my_function()
```

This code produces the following result:

```
Thread started
MyFunction executed
```

To make `thread` a daemon, you can use `thread.setDaemon(True)`. That function must be called before the thread is started:

```
thread = MyThread()
thread.setDaemon(True)
thread.start()
my_function()
```

Comment: @AllExJ Not so sure about that. Long time since I programmed in Python. If I'm right, you'll need multithreading or multiprocessing. You then won't need a daemon, if the process will quit when your program does. When starting a process, code continues to the next line while the process works. I will lookup on multithreading, and create an example here. :)

Comment: solved, I just needed to move "thread.setDaemon(True)" before "thread.start()" But anyway the program, if closed, isn't executing in background

Comment: @AllExJ That is rather strange, since I copied your new code into a .py file, and it all works fine. `my_function` successfully executes. All I changed was to add `pass` to `def daemonize(self):`